# Change Jira Base URL

Tags: jira

Is there a way to change the Base URL of a Jira instance.

JIRA 7.0.5

I remember it asked me when I started it up initially, but I can seem to find a way to change it.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the base URL from the propertystring table:

```
select propertyvalue from propertyentry PE
join propertystring PS on PE.id=PS.id
where PE.property_key = 'jira.baseurl';
```

In order to update the Base URL, run the following update query in your JIRA database replacing the URL and restart JIRA.

```
update propertystring
set propertyvalue = 'http://jira.servername.com'
from propertyentry PE
where PE.id=propertystring.id
and PE.property_key = 'jira.baseurl';
```

more info follow this [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/How+do+I+Manually+Change+The+Base+URL)

Comment: seems to be the only feasible way, as from the application settings page the base url is not changeable...

Comment: Stop Jira, update SQL "update propertystring set propertyvalue = 'http://jira.myserver.com' WHERE id=10187; " then start Jira again

Answer (score 2):

Copy title of question and first google result: https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/configuring-the-server-base-url-148592.html

> Choose the cog icon , then choose General Configuration under Confluence Administration 
>   Choose General Configuration in the left-hand panel 
>   Choose Edit Enter the new URL in the Server Base URL text box 
>   Choose Save
>
> Changing the context path. If you change the context path of your base URL, you may also need to edit the web server's server.xmlfile to reflect the new path:
>
> Stop the Confluence server.
>   Go to your Confluence 'destination directory'. This is the directory where the Confluence installation files are stored. For example,  C:\Program Files\Atlassian\Confluence. Let's call this directory '{CONFLUENCE_INSTALLATION}'.
>   Edit the configuration file at {CONFLUENCE_INSTALLATION}\conf\server.xml.
>   Change the value of the path attribute in the Context element to reflect the context path. For example, if Confluence is running at http://www.foobar.com/confluence, then your path attribute should look like this:

```
<context path="/confluence" docBase="../confluence" debug="0" reloadable'"false" useHttpOnly="true">
```

> Save the file.
>
> Proxies. If you are running behind a proxy, ensure that the proxy name matches the base URL.  For example: proxyName="foobar.com" proxyPort="443" scheme="https". This will make sure we are passing the information correctly.
>   This information needs to be added in the Connector element at {CONFLUENCE_INSTALLATION}\conf\server.xml.

Comment: That's for Confluence, not Jira.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Admin->System->General Configuration

Click Edit Settings

Change Base URL and click Save

Comment: I'm not sure if this was written or applicable at the time of the question, seems too obvious:  https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/configuring-the-base-url-802593107.html

Answer (score 0):

Crackerjoe is correct.

The suggestion given to do it with SQL is **very** bad advice.  Using SQL on JIRA databases is to be avoided, especially when you can, and should, do it in the UI.  If you do use SQL, make sure you have JIRA offline before you do it.